# Copying rows from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

The following script seems like it should work, but I'm getting an "Object defined" error on the lines marked below. I can't find what's causing this at all...

```
Sub MailMerge()
Sheets.Add.Name = "MailMerge"
Dim MailMerge As Worksheet
Set MailMerge = Sheets("MailMerge")
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i, index, lastrow As Long
Dim Abstracts As Worksheet
Set Abstracts = Sheets("Abstracts")

lastrow = Abstracts.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row


For i = 1 To lastrow
    Set Rng = Abstracts.Range("O" & i)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) >= 1 Then
            Abstracts.Range("A" & i).Resize(0, 14).Copy _
            Destination:=MailMerge.Range("A" & i).Resize(0, 14)
            'this is where the error is occuring
         End If
Next

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to `resize` for paste?

Comment: Possibly not. Removing the resize did not resolve the issue, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize is not like OFFSET.  It will set the size of the range to the size dictated.  So you are setting the range size to 0 rows.  It should be 1:

```
Sub MailMerge()
Sheets.Add.Name = "MailMerge"
Dim MailMerge As Worksheet
Set MailMerge = Sheets("MailMerge")
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i, index, lastrow As Long
Dim Abstracts As Worksheet
Set Abstracts = Sheets("Abstracts")

lastrow = Abstracts.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To lastrow
    Set Rng = Abstracts.Range("O" & i)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) >= 1 Then
            Abstracts.Range("A" & i).Resize(1, 14).Copy _
            Destination:=MailMerge.Range("A" & i).Resize(1, 14)
            'this is where the error is occuring
         End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. This solves the issue. I didn't realise resize worked that way. I always wondered why Resize always seemed to 'include' the current cell, while 'Offset' did not. Now I know! :)